# Remove Scroll View and everything in it from the view

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I have a Scroll View which contains a UIImageView and an ActivityIndicator. I would like to programmatically remove the Scroll View from the view, including everything inside it. I have tried doing `scrollView.removeFromSuperview()` (where scrollView is an IBOutlet to the storyboard Scroll View), but I continue to get `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Comment: It should be ```.removeFromSuperview()```. Put a breakpoint at this line and then try to print your _scrollview_ object in the console using ```po scrollview``` to make sure it's not _nil_. If it is not, the problem probably come from somewhere else, where there is an unsafe unwrapping (```!``` or ```?```) in your code. Please provide more information about your console output so we can look into it together.

Comment: @vbuzze I printed out scrollView right before I try to remove it from the superview, and got `some(<UIScrollView: 0x102916c00; frame = (0 0; 375 493); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c065c680>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c0426b80>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 493}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>)`

Comment: @vbuzze I am actually not getting any errors in the console, just the `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: How is the IBOutlet for the scrollView declared? If you declare it with `weak`, then when you call `removeFromSuperview()` the scrollView will be set to nil (because there are no more strong references pointing to it), and any subsequent attempts to access the var will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your outlet on storyboard, I think you forgot binding your outlets with your code.

Comment: I have an IBOutlet for the Scroll View, called `scrollView`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you marked your UIScrollView with `!` as not optional.

Make you outlet optional, it should be like:
`@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?`

and call `removeFromSuperview()` on it, like: `self.scrollView?.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: When I change it to `@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?`, I now get `nil` when printing `scrollView` right before removing it from the superview (and it seems like nothing happens)

Comment: Did you connected `@IBOutlet` with element in Storyboard?